# Viewing Pictures from the RPi on my computer

Tags: sd-card

I had the RPi take a bunch of jpegs with the camera module and save them to the SD card. I would like to view those images on my computer - just plugging in the SD there is no obevious way to do this. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you plugging the sd card into your computer?  Look in /home/pi if that's where you ran the raspistill cmd from.

Comment: The large partition on the sd card us an ext3 file system.  Here's a link that describes 3 ways to access ext3 file systems on windows http://www.howtoforge.com/access-linux-partitions-from-windows

Comment: The pictures are written to a file I have in /home/pi, but when I just plugged the SD card into my computer, that file wasn't showing up anywhere - the only thing showing up were the boot files

Comment: Windows by default only looks at the first partition of an "external" drive, such as the SD card - you need to either use linux or some special software to view all the partitions on the card, or as others have suggested, simply send them from the Pi via other methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to make this a regular use case (getting pictures on your Pi and browsing on computer), you may look at installing miniDLNA and configure the libraries so that the pictures taken are added to the library. In that case you can browse the pictures from you laptop/computer or any other DLNA client (including your TV if it can connect to the DLNA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a usb stick and transfer the files manually, or using the dropbox api setup a synchronisation service. When you have a internet connection you can try to make the pi send the photos by email. Best Regards, Julian Engel

Comment: Oh wow for some reason using a usb drive never even occured to me. That's quite the simple solution, thanks!

Comment: Also, at the time, I wasn't able to access the internet so I couldn't email them to myself

Answer (score 0):

If the RaspberryPi and the computer are networked, You can copy the files to the computer using secure copy.

On your terminal enter,`mkdir myimages && scp -rf username@raspberrypi_ip_address:/path_to/images_folder/* myimages/`. Then enter the password of Rpi and the images will be copied to your home folder

Comment: I do not have them networked, but if I do in the future this will help. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can set up FTP on the Pi, and use some software like filezilla to FTP into it and grab the files that way

just use
`192.168.0.1xx` as the hostname

and `pi / raspberry` as the username/password (if they are still that)